# nextjs - only generate dynamic routes on demand

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using NextJS to build a frontend for a database which currently has few thousand products and this number is expected to grow by a lot. So, my `site/products/` route works fine. I want to add a route to view individual products like `site/products/{sku}`. I created a dynamic route with a dummy component and expected it to work but it I was constantly getting 404 error.

On some research I found that to facilitate dynamic routing, the page component should make use of the `getStatiPaths` and `getStaticProps` to pre-render all the pages so that they can be served.

This behavior would've been useful for a blog, but in my case I don't want to generate few thousand pages everytime I do a `npm run build`. I want to be able to make an API call with the `sku` value I get from the url and generate the page dynamically on the client or better yet do this on the server and send the rendered html to the client.

How do I achieve this, is my thinking wrong in this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61222726/dynamic-routing-with-getserversideprops-in-nextjs/61240697#61240697

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what the [fallback property](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-true) of the object returned by `getStaticPaths` is for:

> - The paths that have not been generated at build time will **not** result in a 404 page. Instead, Next.js will serve a “fallback” version of the page on the first request [...]
> - In the background, Next.js will statically generate the requested path HTML and JSON. [...]
> - At the same time, Next.js adds this path to the list of pre-rendered pages. Subsequent requests to the same path will serve the generated page, like other pages pre-rendered at build time.